# QGIS: Calculate with 2 .tif files creating a third one?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

I got 2 interpolated files (.tif) of the same extend and size and now create a third one using both. More precisly I need to calculate new values (values of file one- values of file two). However I got no ideas how that works and tried out a few tools.Sadly none of them worked.

Comment: In QGIS >Top menu>Raster>Raster Calculator.  So long as your layers match the rest should just be case of understanding the concept of treating layers like variables in an equation

Comment: Please by as precise in your question as possible: "tried out a few tools" or "none of them worked" doesn't help to understand the problem you encountered - we guess that the tools you tried did not work, otherwise you wouldn't ask, would you? So tell us what you've tried and where you're stuck. See [tour].

Comment: Thanks do @Sethinacan, that worked out as intended. Babel, will do the next time i ask something :)

Comment: @Sethinacan can you convert your comment into a proper answer?
Dudelsack123 can you then please accept that answer?

Comment: @AlexandreNeto, I struggle to stretch my solution for the OP into an answer that will be useful for someone else searching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your layers match exactly in terms of resolution and extent you can use the raster calculator.
In QGIS >Top menu>Raster>Raster Calculator.
In the raster calculator each layer is treated like a variable so you can load them into an equation.

```
"Map 1"-"map2"
```

In the example below the equation is a bit messy as my rasters are multi-band
[image]